# Magento - Routing

Tags: apache, magento, xampp

The problem is, I can access my page on

```
http://domain.com:8080/
```

But when I try to go to admin

```
http://domain.com:8080/admin
```

404 Error
But when I add:

```
http://domain.com:8080/index.php/admin
```

It works

I need to set it up working as this

```
http://domain.com:8080/admin
```

My virtualHost looks like

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento"
    ServerName domain.com
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento">           
        Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I was already checking in:

File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php -> _validateControllerClassName

But it doesn't simply go there

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work when you have the standard `.htaccess` file in your project root. The following configuration should rewrite everything which is not pointing to a real file to the `index.php`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

But it will only work if you have mode_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Thank dude, The point was I missed .htaccess file in my root directory :v